# while building project i got this error in values.xml color accetnts not found error

Tags: android

plz help...

> error: resource color/colorAccent (aka
>   com.codexithub.myfood:color/colorAccent) not found.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource color/colorAccent (aka
>   com.codexithub.myfood:color/colorAccent) not found.,
>   sources=[C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\4a52a9c4ea6266b67d07929ad2265ffb\res\values\values.xml:390:5-397:13],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: What project? Do you have some code? Try to make a small sample of your code, the minimum subset of your code that still gives this error and add to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `colorAccent` is not defined in a `res > value > color.xml` file as

```
<color name="colorAccent">#HEX_VALUE</color>
```